# Excel Data Too large to parse. Execution Time Out

Tags: php, laravel, phpexcel

I am using laravel and using https://csv.thephpleague.com/ to parse csv.

My function is something like

```
$path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();
$csv = Reader::createFromPath($path, 'r');
$csv->setHeaderOffset(0); 
$csv_header = $csv->getHeader(); 
$sample_data = $csv->fetchOne(); 
$sample_data = array_values($sample_data);

$records = $reader->getRecords();
 $csv_file_id = Csv_data::create([
        'csv_filename' => $request->file('import_file')->getClientOriginalName(),
        'csv_header' => json_encode($csv_header),
        'csv_data' => json_encode($records)
    ]);
```

How can i parse large data sets, by dealing against execution time limit.

Well, am pretty new to these things, so I request just not commenting like use this and that. Up to now time is just passing by trying this and that package. So, solution with code snippets could be better.

Also I tried with,

```
$stmt = (new Statement())
->offset($offset)
->limit($limit)
;
```

But with no success. !st reason even limiting offset and running in loop by increasing offset, it shows same error of execution time. 2nd reason, its little difficult for me to end the loop with good logic.

Looking for some help. I will be available for instant reply.

Comment: When you're dealing with large data sets like that, making users wait for the process to finish is horrible UX. You'll likely want to set this up on a [Queue](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues) so that the job can run in the background and send an alert once it's finished.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using a console command for this?
https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan

If you run into memory limits when doing through console, you can first try to increase php memory limit.

If that is still not enough, last option is to cut up .csv into parts.
But this should not be necessary unless you are dealing with a very vert large .csv (unlikely).

Comment: He's not using console. He's got references to request in the code

Comment: I am not using console.

Comment: @devk right you are :)
@ Aayush In my opinion you should use a console command which his triggered by a queue job https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/queues

Comment: Hey guys, I got little understand about the queue. But what about the console command, Can it keep you away from execution time out

Answer (score 0):

By default, PHP is usually set to execute a HTTP request for 30 seconds before timing out -- to prevent a runaway script or infinite loop from processing forever.   It sounds like this is what you're running into.

The quick and dirty method is to add `ini_set('max_execution_time', 300);` at the top of your script.  This will tell php to run for 300 seconds (5 minutes) before timing out.

You can adjust that time as needed, but if it regularly takes longer than that, you may want to look at other options -- such as creating a console command (https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/artisan) or running it on a schedule.

Comment: I have already set set 300 sec on php.ini. It is dealing with around 500k rows

Comment: Is it running for the full 5 minutes before timing out or does that happen sooner?  It looks like you're processing a file upload?  I'd suggest writing the data to a temp file and then using an artisan command to do the processing.